# Concat Azure Data Factory Pipeline parameters in SQL Query

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

Azure Data Factory Pipeline is getting the SQL query stored in a database table.
Eg. Query:

```
Select * from employees where first_name = 'Sam' and last_name = 'mathew'
```

I need to update the query in such a way that `fname` and `lname` will be a parameter in the azure data factory pipeline say
`pipeline().parameters.fname` and `pipeline().parameters.lname`

How will the query be modified to use these pipeline parameters in SQL query?

Note: SQL Query is stored in database table. The pipeline will fetch the SQL Query in **Copy Data Pipeline Step**

Comment: Select * from employees where first_name = '@{pipeline().parameters.fname}' and last_name = '@{pipeline().parameters.lname}'


But the best way would be to create a stored procedure with input parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by **@Nandan**, you have to do this by creating a **stored procedure** in the database and **pass the pipeline parameters** in copy activity.

Please follow the demonstration below for that:

- Here I am copying the selected data from query to a csv file in blob. You can copy wherever you want.
- This is my sample **SQL table**.
  [image]
- I am creating stored procedure in the database like below with `fname` and `lname` as parameters and use `concat()` in sql.

```
create or alter procedure dbo.proc1 @fname nvarchar(32),@lname nvarchar(32)
as
begin
    select concat(firstname,' ',lastname) as employee_name from [dbo].[employees] where employees.firstname=@fname and 
    employees.lastname=@lname;
end
```

[image]

- Create a pipeline and **parameters** for `fname` and `lname` with default value like below.

[image]

- Now create a copy activity and give the **SQL table as source** and follow below steps.

[image]

- Give your sink dataset and my case sink is csv file in blob.
- Now, execute pipeline and give the `fname` and `lname` parameter values.

[image]

- Click on ok and you can copy the selected data from the **query in the database** to your sink.

**My Output:**

[image]